# An open sourced copy of Firefox input?

Tags: looking-for-a-script

Is there anything like firefox input http://input.mozilla.com/en-US/ that is open sourced?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code can be found at http://www.github.com/fwenzel/reporter